# How to add new stored procedures to mysql in DataGrip?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, datagrip

I just downloaded DataGrip from JerBrains
How to add new stored procedures to MySQL in DataGrip?

Comment: can you please check the answer below is correct? it helps me and I believe it answers your question.

Answer (score 18):

- Configure a connection
- Then open new console for that data source.
- In console press `Alt+Insert` that will suggest you to generate code for different objects.
- After filling template, press `Ctrl + Enter` to execute

Done!

Answer (score 1):

It is very poor in managing stored procedures or functions in `Data Grip`, for Mac Users:

- `Shift+Cmd+F10` to open a new console where you can write a script and create a new object (SP, view, function ..etc)

Also, To change or alter a Stored procedure, you can generate a SQL script for your data source, `Right click` on `data source`, then from `SQL Scripts` menu click `Generate DDL to console`

- `Opt+Shift+Cmd+B` to generate DDL to console
- `Cmd+Opt+G` to generate all SQL scripts for the selected datasource
- `Cmd+Enter` to execute your script